# Create rows of intermediary dates

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm looking to get the number of tickets that are unassigned at the end of each day over a specified period of days using historical data. I'm using Amazon Redshift.

The query currently has this structure:

| ticket_id | created_at | assigned_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-18 | 2020-11-20 |
| 2 | 2020-11-18 | 2020-11-18 |
| 3 | 2020-11-17 | 2020-11-20 |

My current strategy is to use the created_at date, create a new row with the created_date + 1 day until it is the same as the assigned_at date. From there I can easily manipulate the output with Tableau.

The output that I'm looking for is:

| ticket_id | created_at | assigned_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-18 | 2020-11-20 |
| 1 | 2020-11-19 | 2020-11-20 |
| 1 | 2020-11-20 | 2020-11-20 |
| 2 | 2020-11-18 | 2020-11-18 |
| 3 | 2020-11-17 | 2020-11-20 |
| 3 | 2020-11-18 | 2020-11-20 |
| 3 | 2020-11-19 | 2020-11-20 |
| 3 | 2020-11-20 | 2020-11-20 |

In the end I want to be able to get to this:

| date | tickets in queue |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11-17 | 1 |
| 2020-11-18 | 2 |
| 2020-11-19 | 2 |
| 2020-11-20 | 0 |

I'm also open to other suggestions regarding how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an additional table with calendar

```sql
create table calendar (
    calendar_date date
);
```

| calendar_date |
| --- |
| 2020-11-17 |
| 2020-11-18 |
| 2020-11-19 |
| 2020-11-20 |

then join against it

```sql
select calendar_date, count(*) 
from table_name as t 
    left join calendar as c on t.created_at <= c.calendar_date 
                            and c.calendar_date < t.assigned_at 
where c.calendar_date <> t.assigned_at 
group by 1
order by 1;
```

it gives the following output

| calendar_date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11-17 | 1 |
| 2020-11-18 | 2 |
| 2020-11-19 | 2 |

2020-11-20 is absent in this result as there's no ticket

You can get it with a bit complex query

```sql
with calendar_gr as (
    select calendar_date, 0 as cnt
    from calendar
),
r1 as (
    select calendar_date, count(*)  
    from table_name as t 
        left join calendar as c on t.created_at <= c.calendar_date 
                                and c.calendar_date < t.assigned_at                         
    where calendar_date <> assigned_at 
    group by 1
    order by 1
)
select calendar_gr.calendar_date, sum(coalesce(count, 0) + coalesce(cnt, 0)) 
from r1
    right join calendar_gr on r1.calendar_date = calendar_gr.calendar_date
group by 1
;
```

| calendar_date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11-17 | 1 |
| 2020-11-18 | 2 |
| 2020-11-19 | 2 |
| 2020-11-20 | 0 |

Comment: This method works and performs well for small to medium data sets.  I would recommend a solution along these lines for most cases.  However, if the dataset is very large and date ranges between created_at and assigned_at are wide there can be a large amount of intermediate data records created by this process.  If this intermediate data size expands beyond memory then the query spills and slows down massively.  There are solutions for these cases but they take some time to layout.  I can write up such a solution but only if the use case in question runs into spill issues.

Comment: Hi Bill, when not setting restrictions I am running into an EOF error so I think you're right. Restricting the dates, as we'll be doing, allows me to avoid this though.